# Проблема с отрисовкой картинки через StretchDIBits

Tags: delphi, winapi, canvas, изображения, radstudio

Всем здрасте! У меня возникла проблема с отрисовкой кадра из видео через StretchDIBits из моей dll в родительском приложении. Проблема заключается в том что если рисовать при помощи OpenGL то все рисуется нормально, а если использовать StretchDIBits то изображение искажается 
вот как я вызываю StretchDIBits:

```
    StretchDIBits(dc,0,0,ScreenWidth,ScreenHeigth,0,0,fFormat.bmiHeader.biWidth,fFormat.bmiHeader.biHeight,Bits,PBitmapInfo(@fFormat.bmiHeader)^,DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
```

Формат входного изображения в функцию 24bit

Фото прилагается [image: Кадр отрисованный при помощи OpenGL и StretchDIBits]

Answer (score 3):

Все спасибо, проблема решена, нужно было оказывается перед StretchDIBits вызывать

```
SetStretchBltMode(dc,HALFTONE);
```